# How does React's useEffect work when the array has more than one element?

Tags: reactjs

Probably a basic question, but I have doubts on how works a useEffect with more than one element in the array. Given:

```
useEffect(()=>{alert("hi");},[one,two]);
```

Does the alert appear when one and two matches like if it was `one && two` or is it an `or` condition like "one || two"?

Also, is it possible to use comparison as well in the array like
`useEffect(()=>{alert("hi");},[one===true,two===false]);` ?

Comment: It will trigger if *either* of the values have changed

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect):

> The default behavior for effects is to fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is always recreated if **one** of its dependencies changes.

Comment: That is, *at least one*, not *exactly one*, before someone asks.